# When ever new case is created notification will be trigger on web email address

Tags: workflow, process-builder, email-alert, email2case, case-auto-response

```
Error element myRule_1_A1 (FlowActionCall).
Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients 
________________________________________
Flow Details
Flow API Name: SSC_CAS_PB04_CaseCreationNotification
Type: Record Change Process
Version: 3
Status: Active
Org: CMA CGM SA (00D0E000000Dtnx)
Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: SSC_CAS_PB04_CaseCreationNotification-3_InterviewLabel
Current User: Rihanath basha (0050E000005tMQg)
Start time: 22/01/2020 14:53
Duration: 0 seconds
How the Interview Started
Rihanath basha (0050E000005tMQg) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = null
myVariable_current = Case (5000E000009tnU3QAI)
RecursiveCountVariable = 0,00
DECISION: myDecision
Outcome executed: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: 
1. {!myVariable_current.Origin} (Email) Equals Email
2. {!myVariable_current.OwnerId} (00G0E000004any6UAA) Equals 00G0E000004any6UAA
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
CASE.SSC_OOG_CASE_CREATION_NOTIFICATION (EMAIL ALERTS): myRule_1_A1
Inputs:
SObjectRowId = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5000E000009tnU3QAI)
________________________________________
Error Occurred: Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients 
________________________________________
________________________________________
Salesforce Error ID: 1402564926-520867 (468635505)
```

Comment: That's a gack. Only Salesforce Support can explain what that specific error Id means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Error Occurred: Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients

is explained in this [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320056&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

I'm assuming you have some sort of **email alert** going out as an action on your process builder. This email alert is trying to send an email, but there's no recipients or the recipient is a user who is inactive.

[image]

Comment: using web email field

Comment: Thank you for your documents but still wont work for those process.. please let me know

Comment: The documents do explain what's the issue (trying to send an email with no recipient). You most likely need to add a check in your process builder to make sure web email field is not blank before sending an email.